# Android tabbed Activity

Tags: android, tabactivity

I have created tabs using intents.MainPage.java is my class that extends TabActivity and other 5 activites that extends Activity which i have added as tabs. I need to get Strings from the 5 activities which i have added as tabs once a click is performed in the MainPage.java class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation:

> The TabActivity class is deprecated. New applications should use
>   Fragments instead of this class; to continue to run on older devices,
>   you can use the v4 support library which provides a version of the
>   Fragment API that is compatible down to DONUT.

[**Here**](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_fragments/) are some [**`Fragment`**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) tutorials to help you get [**started**](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/02/android-30-fragments-api.html).

Also, check out [**`FragmentTabs.java`**](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentTabs.html) on the developer site.